# Is there a software that can predict the shape of a custom protein, given its amino acid sequence?

Tags: computational-chemistry, biochemistry, theoretical-chemistry, chemical-biology, enzymes

I know that the internet is full of enzyme and protein simulators which can show active site and 3D structure (like bioblender), but the problem with these programs is that they use predefined information and coordinates supplied by several databases (such as PDB ) , but actually I didn't find a software that can predict the shape of a custom protein with custom amino acid sequence. So, do you know such software?

Comment: It's not a trivial task, so the shortest answer is: there is no such software. Actually, a more complex answer would imply homology modeling and molecular dynamics, but the procedures are quite elaborate, and there are not "black box" pieces of software for that

Comment: +1 to @The_Vinz, very good answer. Would you consider committing to the Materials Modeling Stack Exchange? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ODMyMDc3YzliMTY4MzI1YzcyMjczOGNlYWQ3Yjk1MTkxM2Q3NGIyYzM1MzcwYzdmNmE3ZjhiYmYzNzA5Njg2N7YXbfH40JIpwIJ67zouTLfOm4fPVJM-PNoOsMCnOzzc0

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_protein_structure_prediction_software

Comment: There might one day be such software but I do not think it has been written yet, it is a very difficult thing to do. It might be better to obtain some of the protein and then use NMR or crystallography to determine the 3D shape.